# Windows task scheduler is giving error when trying to set it via bsub

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, escaping

When I am running command:

`SCHTASKS /create  /tn "ADW_generic" /s noivw-pulsereg3 /tr "\"U:\adw_prerun_bat_file\filesToUseInAutomatedPvReg\ADWGeneric_cic.bat\" -var 23232 "  /sc ONCE /sd 12/29/2014 /st 12:00  /f`

then no issue is coming.

But, when I am running the same command via bsub (using system) in perl as follows:

```
my $cmdTriggerServerSetup = "bsub -J ADWServer -m machine1 -e //noida02/psd/error_tette.log -q win_normal \'SCHTASKS /create  /tn \"ADW_generic\" /s noivw-pulsereg3 /tr \"\"U:\\adw_prerun_bat_file\\filesToUseInAutomatedPvReg\\ADWGeneric_cic.bat\" -var 23232 \"  /sc ONCE /sd 12/29/2014 /st 12:00  /f\'";
```

getting the Following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '-var'.
Type "SCHTASKS /CREATE /?" for usage.
```

How can I get rid of this error? I know the error is somewhat because of quotes, thus want help in figuring  out how shall the quotes be added to the command.

I want the required string to be
`SCHTASKS /create  /tn "ADW_generic" /s noivw-pulsereg3 /tr "\"U:\adw_prerun_bat_file\filesToUseInAutomatedPvReg\ADWGeneric_cic.bat\" -var 23232 "  /sc ONCE /sd 12/29/2014 /st 12:00  /f`

but when I am using as:

```
my $cmdTriggerServerSetup = "bsub -J ADWServer -m machine1 -e //noida02/psd/error_tette.log -q win_normal \'SCHTASKS /create  /tn \"ADW_generic\" /s noivw-pulsereg3 /tr \"\\"U:\\adw_prerun_bat_file\\filesToUseInAutomatedPvReg\\ADWGeneric_cic.bat\\" -var 23232 \"  /sc ONCE /sd 12/29/2014 /st 12:00  /f\'";
```

it is giving me an error as:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at test.pl line 24, near "U"
        (Missing operator before U?)
```

---

I followed what is being asked in the below answer by ikegami:

```
my $var1="23232";
my $testScriptBuilder2=sub {
    my $relName=$_[0];
    return "SCHTASKS /create  /tn \"ADW_generic\" /s noivw-pulsereg3 /tr \"\\"U:\\adw_prerun_bat_file\\filesToUseInAutomatedPvReg\\ADWGeneric_cic.bat\\" -var $var1\"  /sc ONCE /sd 12/29/2014 /st 12:00  /f";
};

my $testCommand=$testScriptBuilder->($relName);



system(
   bsub => (
      -J => "ADWServer",
      -m => "spb2k864svr2",
      -e => "//noinapb02/psdstore4/pvts_CM/bin.wint/LSF_work/logs/machine_health_check/22.1_ISR/error_tette.log",
      -q => "win_normal",
      $testCommand,
   )
);
```

On running this script, I am getting  error:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '-var'.
Type "SCHTASKS /CREATE /?" for usage.
```

But, when I am running it on a shell command line, it is running fine. Command that is being generated by above command builder is :

```
SCHTASKS /create  /tn "ADW_generic" /s noivw-pulsereg3 /tr "\"U:\adw_prerun_bat_file\filesToUseInAutomatedPvReg\ADWGeneric_cic.bat\" -var 23232"  /sc ONCE /sd 12/29/2014 /st 12:00  /f
```

Comment: Your quoting may be incorrect, try using single quotes for the string, or `qq`/`q` instead.

Comment: @ikegami, utils::execCommand is like a system command. It's a package used with perl. Required string is what I mentioned first that is running correct with no issues: `SCHTASKS /create  /tn "ADW_generic" /s noivw-pulsereg3 /tr "\"U:\adw_prerun_bat_file\filesToUseInAutomatedPvReg\ADWGeneric_cic.bat\" -var 23232 "  /sc ONCE /sd 12/29/2014 /st 12:00  /f`

Comment: @RawleyFowler, what is qq/q?

Comment: @ikegami, bsub is running from csh shell. And I am not sure of the working bsub command. If I had known, I wouldn't have asked here.

Comment: @ikegami, I have removed it (utils::execCommand) from the post, Now, it is a system command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255686/discussion-between-ppp-and-ikegami).

Comment: @ikegami, let's continue in the chat. We will then add the conclusion here

Answer (score 1):

We want to build some commands. To build them, we're going to need this:

```perl
use String::ShellQuote qw( );
use Win32::ShellQuote  qw( );  # Can be installed and used on any platform.

# Import with custom names.
BEGIN { *quote_for_sh    = \&String::ShellQuote::shell_quote; }
BEGIN { *quote_for_win32 = \&Win32::ShellQuote::quote_native; }
```

First, we need to build a Windows command.

```perl
my $task = quote_for_win32(
   'U:\\adw_prerun_bat_file\\filesToUseInAutomatedPvReg\\ADWGeneric_cic.bat' => (
      -var => $var1,
   )
);
```

Then another.

```perl
my $remote_cmd = quote_for_win32(
   schtasks => (
      "/create",
      "/tn" => "ADW_generic",
      "/s"  => "noivw-pulsereg3",
      "/tr" => $task,
      "/sc" => "ONCE",
      "/sd" => "12/29/2014",
      "/st" => "12:00",
      "/f",
   )
);
```

We could build a sh command to pass to `system` here.

```perl
my $local_cmd = quote_for_sh(
   bsub => (
      -J => "ADWServer",
      -m => "machine1",
      -e => "//noida02/psd/error_tette.log",
      -q => "win_normal",
      $remote_cmd,
   )
);
```

But we could just launch `bsub` directly instead of using a shell intermediary.

```perl
system(
   bsub => (
      -J => "ADWServer",
      -m => "machine1",
      -e => "//noida02/psd/error_tette.log",
      -q => "win_normal",
      $remote_cmd,
   )
);
```

If you need to capture the output or whatever, use IPC::Run's `run` instead of `system`.

Comment: Getting the same error `ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '-var'.
Type "SCHTASKS /CREATE /?" for usage.`
after using 2nd approach (avoiding shell_quote):

Comment: `my $remote_cmd = 'SCHTASKS /create  /tn \"ADW_generic\" /s noivw-pulsereg3 /tr \"\"U:\\adw_prerun_bat_file\\filesToUseInAutomatedPvReg\\ADWGeneric_cic.bat\" -var 23232\"  /sc ONCE /sd 12/29/2014 /st 12:00  /f';` worked . But, what if i want to make -var $var1 as (`my $remote_cmd = 'SCHTASKS /create  /tn \"ADW_generic\" /s noivw-pulsereg3 /tr \"\"U:\\adw_prerun_bat_file\\filesToUseInAutomatedPvReg\\ADWGeneric_cic.bat\" -var \'$var1\'\"  /sc ONCE /sd 12/29/2014 /st 12:00  /f';`)

Comment: See update. ___

Comment: I followed what you said, but in a different way, and still getting the error. I am adding that to the notes below.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But, some issue is still coming. I updated that in my question itself. Can you please help? It seems a problem of quotes.

Comment: Re "*I followed what you said*", huh? Not remotely close.

Comment: See also [Qouting the Shell](https://www.perl.com/article/quoting-the-shell/), which is not Windows specific but shows some of the things you need to think about.

Comment: As part of what ikegami has already said, I usually build that stuff up in an array so I can output the command to see what actually got in there. I have no idea what `bsub` is but if it is running what you give it in yet another shell, you might find that you have to quote the top level so that the second level is also quoted correctly for the shell. I've had to run some ssh commands that hopped through several servers, and quoting for each hop was the most frustrating part.